# MusicKit gets stuck on the loading screen when trying to login with Apple Music (for media contols)

Tags: android, ios, apple-musickit, apple-sign-in

I'm trying to use Apple's official MusicKit SDK for Android, I downloaded their example project for Android from [here](https://developer.apple.com/musickit/), and in the R.string file I replaced the JWT placeholder with my actual JWT token (which works for me with Apple Music Web API) and I'm trying to login with my Apple Music account to the example app so I can control the apple music media (play/pause/prev/next buttons) from within the example app, but when I try to open the login page it opens a new activity in the Apple Music app and it never finishes loading, it only shows the progressBar and never let me insert my login info.

I've been trying to solve this problem for the past week or so, I'd love to get some help :)

Comment: Where are you entering this domain? Sign in with Apple isn't required to access Apple Music. Sign in with Apple is still beta while MusicKit is released and provides different methods for obtaining user authentication via your developer entitlements

Comment: @Paulw11 In the "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" there's a "more" section where you can click "configure" and insert your domain name and email address..

So if there's no need for it then do you know why does their example Android app won't work?
I have Apple Music installed on my Android device and I downloaded their example project for android and changed the JWT token in R.string to my own JWT token (which works for me on Apple Music Web API) but on android it stucks on the loading screen when I try to login, there are no errors or time outs, it just shows the loading screen

Comment: The screen in the developer site you are referring to is for configuring email relaying when the user chooses not to share their actual email address with you when using the new sign in with Apple feature. This is nothing to do with Apple Music.  You should edit your question to show the code you are using and explain your problem more clearly. You should also tag Android and music kit

Comment: @Paulw11 I edited my question and added some info about the problem.. In regard to showing my code, I'm using apple's official example project and I replaced the JWT token placeholder with my own JWT token (which works for me for their Web API), so if you want to try to do what I'm doing, just download the exmaple project from here: https://developer.apple.com/musickit/ , and replcae the JWT token in the R.string file and run the app on your device (don't forget to install Apple music), and if you are actually trying it I'd love to get an update if it's working for you.. :)

Comment: Any chance you got this figured out? Doing the same now and getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably too late to answer this but since there are no answers posted for this question I will tell how it got fixed for me.

In order to authenticate a user for Apple Music, you need a developer token. I think there is some timeout or logic associated with the token expiry. After I refreshed this developer token, it worked for me.